# OpenCV: How do I proceed to pick up the n best descriptors of an image using SIFT?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, sift

I'm implementing SIFT with OpenCV, and would like to build a dataset of images descriptors, but just pick up only the n best (200 best, 300...)

Comment: How will you define _best_?

Comment: best = high score :)

Comment: This is my question is there any algorithm that rank keypoints.

Comment: other question, why you want to keep only say 200 keypoints per image?

Comment: Since I want to store the descriptors in the training matrix for the SVM and the size of all descriptors should be the same,Is it clear now ?

Comment: Yes, see my answer. However, you usually don't do like that, but compute a gobal descriptor, such as Bag of Word, that will always have the same length independently from the number of keypoints detected in an image.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your suggestion ,what u mean by gobal descriptor

Comment: SIFT is a _local_ descriptor. It contains information only of a small portion of the image (a 32x32 window if I remember correctly). A _global_ descriptor like BoW contains information about all the image. That's why when you compare images you'd better use global descriptors.

Comment: How can I use BoW in openCV ?

Comment: Quite funny... OpenCV has [BOWImgDescriptorExtractor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html), but again there seems not to be in the Java wrapper. However, it's not difficult to implement. Any chance you switch to C++ code? :D

Comment: A global descriptor describes the whole image. They are generally not very robust as a change in part of the image may cause it to fail as it will effect the resulting descriptor.

BUT a local descriptor describes a patch within an image. Multiple local descriptors are used to match an image and this is more robust as not all the descriptors need to match for the comparison to be made. This makes them more robust to changes between the matched images.

Comment: Yeah, that blog is not that accurate.. :D

Comment: If you need to find the exact same object, the you're ok with local descriptors (but you don't need svm for that). If you want to find a class of objects (E.g. Cars, planes, etc) you'd better use global descriptors. Without knowing you final is impossible to say further. Btw, the excerpt you posted is not accurate. It depends on how you compute the global desc, how you compare local desc, and what is the final goal. That excerpt is perfect if you want to find the exact same object in a different image with similar pose, illumination etc. It's wrong in any other case.

Comment: What about image matching for currency identifier ?

Comment: It largely depends on your input images. Smartphone cam or high quality scanner? Picture in the wild or with know background? Same lighting and occlusion conditions? Coins (rigid) or bills (non-rigid)? Same currency or different (say USD and EUR)? etc... This is my last post on this question, since this discussion is no more related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for [SIFT](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html?sift-sift)

> SIFT::SIFT(int nfeatures=0, int nOctaveLayers=3, double contrastThreshold=0.04, double edgeThreshold=10, double sigma=1.6)
>
> **nfeatures** – The number of best features to retain. The features are ranked by their scores (measured in SIFT algorithm as the local contrast)

So you can simply pass `nfeatures = 200` in the constructor to keep the *best* 200 keypoints.

Comment: But in java the code will be like that and there is no other parameters can I add them :                                                                         DescriptorExtractor descriptorExtractor =          DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SIFT);

Comment: @Walaa Through that interface you can call the default constructor only. You need to call the SIFT constructor explicitly.

Comment: I try to do that but I did not fount it explicitly in OpenCV 2.4.8

Comment: it seems that in Java you don't have the bindings to do that.. but I can't be sure